# Extracting hex-part of string

Tags: string, bash, hex, extract

i have a string like

```
70100100700FF0101621B52FF55FFFFAFD30177078181C7820
```

and i need the 8 characters following the `52FF55` part. so the result should be `FFFFAFD3`. the `52FF55` is static, all other string parts are variable.

i have to use a bash shell script.

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep -oP` with `lookbehind regex`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=52FF55).{8}' <<< "$s"
FFFFAFD3
```

OR `sed -r`:

```
sed -r 's/^.*52FF55(.{8}).*$/\1/' <<< "$s"
FFFFAFD3
```